# When can an enterprise architecture framework be used to document a solution architecture?

Tags: togaf, enterprise-architecture

While documenting solution architectures I use frameworks such as the following to provide structure for the Architecture Description document (see below):

- [Viewpoints and Perspectives](http://www.viewpoints-and-perspectives.info/)
- [4+1 View](http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rational/web/whitepapers/2003/Pbk4p1.pdf)

However, I've also seen people use Enterprise Architecture concepts to structure their Architecture Descriptions, using document headings such as TOGAF's:

- Business Architecture
- Functional Architecture
- Data Architecture
- Application Architecture
- Etc.,

**Question:** Are Enterprise Architecture frameworks suitable for documenting Solution Architectures?

---

> *Definition*:
>
> **Architecture Description** (AD): A collection of products to document an architecture (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1471#IEEE_Terminology_related_to_software_architecture)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenGroup have created [ArchiMate](http://www.opengroup.org/subjectareas/enterprise/archimate) as a tool for architecture modeling. It's designed to be in line with TOGAF, so a description of a solution architecture using ArchiMate would be full of those TOGAF terms.

Comment: This was interesting: [Archimate 2.0 for Solution Architects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i5BGqg-Zho)

Answer (score 5):

The term "Enterprise Architecture Framework" (EAF) is a very broad term. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760643/2615437) contains [a link to an helpful orientation (including some historical overview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466232.aspx) how differently the term is used.

If you choose the right definition - and perhaps use only a subset of a given EAF - then the answer is: "Yes, they are suitable!" But since some EAFs might focus on something totally different (e.g. the process how you got to your architecture and not on the documentation of the architecture) the answer might also be: "They are not."

For your purpose (structuring architecture artifacts) the [taxonomy provided by Zachmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zachman_Framework) might be a good fit. But I would argue that your current way of structuring it fits well into some of the other EAFs that doesn't define how the architectural artifacts are to be structured.

Answer (score 0):

An enterprise architecture (EA) framework can be used to document a solution architecture in cases where the solution architecture aligns with and contributes to the broader goals and objectives of the enterprise.

An enterprise architecture framework provides a structured and standardized approach to developing and managing an organization's overall architecture, including its business, information, application, and technology architectures. Solution architecture, on the other hand, focuses on the design and implementation of a specific solution to a particular business problem or opportunity.

In some cases, a solution architecture may be a component of a broader enterprise architecture, and therefore can be documented using the same EA framework used for the broader architecture. For example, if a solution architecture is designed to support a specific business process or capability, it may be aligned with and built on top of the enterprise's existing business architecture.

However, it's important to note that a solution architecture may have unique requirements and considerations that are not captured in the enterprise architecture framework. In such cases, it may be necessary to augment or customize the EA framework to ensure that the specific needs of the solution architecture are addressed.

Overall, the decision to use an enterprise architecture framework to document a solution architecture should be based on the degree to which the solution architecture aligns with and contributes to the broader goals and objectives of the enterprise, and whether the EA framework can adequately capture and address the unique requirements and considerations of the solution architecture.